# Vertically align img/button in center of article (parent tag)

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I style my play button/img so that it is horizontally aligned in the center of the article tag? I'd like the button/img to remain in the center of the panel as the width of the responsive panels change as the browser window width changes.

html / js:

```
            jQuery('<img/>', {
                src: '/img/youtubeIcon.png',
                class: 'youtubeIcon'
            }).appendTo('#article'+i)

            jQuery('<button/>', {
                id: 'playBtn'+i,
                class: 'playBtn'
            }).appendTo('#article'+i)

            jQuery('<img/>', {
                src: '/img/playIcon.png'
            }).appendTo('#playBtn'+i)
```

css:

```
.playBtn {
    top: 25;
    position: relative;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.playBtn img{
    width: 50;
}
```

https://github.com/leptone/panels/blob/master/public/index.html#L53

Comment: Don't post code link here. Instead post actual code.

Comment: for your css you should use some measurement units as well... like **top: 25**what?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to align it horizontally you can simply get the elements parent and have a **text-align: center;** put in its CSS.

Also there is a complete guide that I found useful for any kind of alignment [here](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/).

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer does not support using the ‘display: none’ style on OPTION elements inside a SELECT list.

For example, the below would work in FireFox and Google Chrome but not Internet Explorer.

```
<select>
<option value=“volvo”>Volvo</option>
<option style=”display: none” value=“saab”>Saab</option>
<option value=“mercedes”>Mercedes</option>
<option value=“audi”>Audi</option>
</select>
```

Since Internet Explore will not hide an option you instead need to disable it. In Internet Explorer this will color the option light grey and not allow it to be selected.

The following jQuery will work in Internet Explorer, Firefox and Goolge Chrome (as well as other browsers). it will hide and disable the option:

```
$('select option[value=saab]').attr('disabled', 'disabled').hide();
Note – replace $ with jQuery if you are using WordPress.

jQuery-HideSelectOption1
```

If you do not already have jQuery loaded on the page, you will need to include it. The easiest way is to include the following line in your page head.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
To display or enable the option again, using the following jQuery:

$('select option[value=saab]').removeAttr('disabled').show()
jQuery-HideSelectOption2
```